# Why does multiprocessing logging work without a QueueListener?

Tags: python, logging, multiprocessing, python-logging

I have a multiprocessing setup, with a worker function and a parent function. Here is a simplified version:

```py
from functools import partial
from typing import List
import logging
from logging.handlers import QueueHandler, QueueListener
from multiprocessing import Manager, Pool, Queue

def parent_func(log_file: str, task_list: List[str]):
    # Setup the root logger
    logger = getLogger()
    logger.addHandler(FileHandler(log_file))

    # Setup the logging listener, which should log to the log file and to stdout
    manager = Manager()
    queue = manager.Queue()
    # Copy all handlers from the root logger
    listener = QueueListener(queue, *logger.handlers)
    listener.start()

    # Fork into workers
    with Pool() as pool:
        func = partial(
            worker_func,
            logging_queue=queue,
        )
        pool.map(func, task_list)
    listener.stop()

def worker_func(
    data: str,
    logging_queue: Queue,
): 
    # Note: this logger is totally disconnected from the parent logger since it shares no handlers
    logger = getLogger(data)
    logger.handlers = []
    logger.addHandler(QueueHandler(logging_queue))

    logger.info("Processing {}".format(data))
```

The problems are:

- Using this code, each `logger.info` call in the worker function logs everything to stdout twice, and
- If I remove the `listener` variable entirely, I somehow still receive logs from the worker functions (even though they're running on a different process!)

This implies that I'm doing something very wrong, because the logging queue doesn't even seem to be necessary. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You're initializing QueueHandler of the worker using the same queue that parent has already initialized with its own handlers. Could this be the issue?

Comment: I believe you're supposed to use the same queue. For reference: https://docs.python.org/3/howto/logging-cookbook.html#a-more-elaborate-multiprocessing-example

Comment: Please post how the main program sets up and runs from `if __name__ == '__main__':`

Comment: Please state which platform you are using, Windows or Linux? Also, please add a minimal reproducible code example.